# How to get access_token of a secret facebook group that I don't manage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Facebook Graph API to obtain every post from a secret facebook group. Notice that it won't work with `user_groups` or `user_managed_groups`.

From what I've read so far I need to get an access_token for the group which I'm having troubles understanding how to obtain. I see a lot of articles on getting the access_token of a public groups or managed ones.

How to deal with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get an "access token of a group" you're not an admin of with Graph API v2.4.

The `user_groups` permission is deprecated:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

> The user_groups permission has been deprecated. Developers may continue to use the user_managed_groups permission to access the groups a person is the administrator of. This information is still accessed via the /v2.4/{user_id}/groups edge which is still available in v2.4.